# SQL Query Help - Kit Structure Join to Attributes

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having issue figuring out a SQL query...

I'm working with two tables. The first is the **kit structure (K)**, where in general a given kit has multiple components (e.g., kit K1 has components K1_A & K1_B, kit K2 has components K2_A, K2_B, K2_C, etc.):

```
    +-----+------+
    | Kit | Comp |
    +-----+------+
    | K1  | K1_A |
    | K1  | K1_B |
    | K2  | K2_A |
    | K2  | K2_B |
    | K2  | K2_C |
    | K3  | K4   |
    | K4  | K4_A |
    | …   | …    |
    +-----+------+
```

(**K** is shown simplified, actual table has many additional columns and kits/components, and not ordered)

NOTE: Table updated from original. To clarify, one thing to observe here is that kits are generally multi-leveled, e.g., K3 (kit) contains component K4 (comp), which in turn is in K.Kit with component K4_A, etc.

The second table has all the **item attributes (I)** (cost, inventory on hand, etc.) as line-items for *both* kits and components:

```
    +------+------------+------------+
    | Item |   Attr1    |   Attr2    |
    +------+------------+------------+
    | K1   | (for K1)   | (for K1)   |
    | K1_A | (for K1_A) | (for K1_A) |
    | K1_B | (for K1_B) | (for K1_B) |
    | K2   | (for K2)   | (for K2)   |
    | K2_A | (for K2_A) | (for K2_A) |
    | K2_B | (for K2_B) | (for K2_B) |
    | K2_C | (for K2_C) | (for K2_C) |
    | K3   | (for K3)   | (for K3)   |
    | K4   | (for K4)   | (for K4)   |
    | K4_A | (for K4_A) | (for K4_A) |
    | …    | …          | …          |
    +------+------------+------------+
```

(**I** is similarly shown in simplified form for easier reference)

I'm trying to join the tables such that the kit structure is outputted showing the corresponding attributes with respect to the kit's *components*, i.e., the following **desired result**:

```
    +-----+------+------+------------+------------+
    | Kit | Comp | Item |   Attr1    |   Attr2    |
    +-----+------+------+------------+------------+
    | K1  | K1_A | K1_A | (for K1_A) | (for K1_A) |
    | K1  | K1_B | K1_B | (for K1_B) | (for K1_B) |
    | K2  | K2_A | K2_A | (for K2_A) | (for K2_A) |
    | K2  | K2_B | K2_B | (for K2_B) | (for K2_B) |
    | K2  | K2_C | K2_C | (for K2_C) | (for K2_C) |
    | K3  | K4   | K4   | (for K4)   | (for K4)   |
    | K4  | K4_A | K4_A | (for K4_A) | (for K4_A) |
    | …   | …    | …    | …          | …          |
    +-----+------+------+------------+------------+
```

(Note: I'm just looking for one level down relative to the kit (i.e., kit Lvl0 to Comp Lvl1), not the full recursive BOM depth)

My attempted SQL query was as follows:

```
    SELECT K.Kit, K.Comp, I.Item, I.Atrr1, I.Attr2
    FROM K
    JOIN I
    ON K.Kit = I.Item
```

This is not working, however, because it is joining through to the (repeated) attributes of the *kits* rather than the *components*, i.e., the following **incorrect output**:

```
    +-----+------+------+----------+----------+
    | Kit | Comp | Item |  Attr1   |  Attr2   |
    +-----+------+------+----------+----------+
    | K1  | K1_A | K1   | (for K1) | (for K1) |
    | K1  | K1_B | K1   | (for K1) | (for K1) |
    | K2  | K2_A | K2   | (for K2) | (for K2) |
    | K2  | K2_B | K2   | (for K2) | (for K2) |
    | K2  | K2_C | K2   | (for K2) | (for K2) |
    | K3  | K4   | K3   | (for K3) | (for K3) |
    | K4  | K4_A | K4   | (for K4) | (for K4) |
    | …   | …    | …    | …        | …        |
    +-----+------+------+----------+----------+
```

Any advice is appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Update: Added formatted tables and MySQL tag

Comment: Please tag your DBMS. Also, well formatted text is preferable to images.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you just want to join on comp instead?

```
SELECT K.Kit, K.Comp, I.Item, I.Atrr1, I.Attr2
FROM K
JOIN I
ON K.comp = I.Item
```

Comment: That was what I also tried, but the issue there is it loses the kit structure and just outputs the component attributes, which is essentially just the table I itself. That's where I'm stuck, is maintaining the KIT STRUCTURE through to the table I...I don't know if maybe I need to do some kind of self join first? NOTE: On a related point, I failed to mention originally that K.Comp also contains items that are in K.Kit, i.e., multi-level kits. So, for example, K1 (Kit) -> K1_A (Comp), but K1_A (Kit) -> K2 (Comp). Sorry, should've clarified that on the outset!

Comment: Not totally following. It would be helpful if you provided the results that you'd like to see in the question.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, I just updated accordingly after my comment...Thanks!